# How to achieve MAX(COUNT(columnName))

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have the following table columns:

```
CommunicationNumber, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot
```

I want to count the number of rows for each `CommunicationNumber` where `DayOfWeekSlot` and `TwoHourSlot` are the same. From this result I want to select the row where the count of `(DayOfWeekSlot/TwoHourSlot)` is the highest.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT tblLog.CommunicationNumber, MAX(tblLog.Priority) AS Frequency, tblLog.DayOfWeekSlot, tblLog.TwoHourSlot
FROM (SELECT CommunicationNumber, Count(*) AS Priority, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot 
        FROM Miafon.dbo.tblPhoneLogRep
        WHERE CallDuration > 0
        GROUP BY CommunicationNumber, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot) tblLog
GROUP BY tblLog.CommunicationNumber, tblLog.DayOfWeekSlot, tblLog.TwoHourSlot
ORDER BY tblLog.CommunicationNumber, Frequency DESC
```

The above query gives me the following columns:

```
CommunicationNumber, Frequency, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot
```

Since I group by `CommunicationNumber`, `TwoHourSlot` and `DayOfWeekSlot`, I get all rows where these values differ (sorted in decreasing order of frequency). I only want the row with the highest value of frequency.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: row_number() over ....

Comment: What you want is `Max(Count)`, not `Count(Max)`.

Comment: Thanks @StefanSteinegger. Fixed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number for that matter like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT tblLog.CommunicationNumber, tblLog.Priority AS Frequency, tblLog.DayOfWeekSlot, tblLog.TwoHourSlot
    ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY tblLog.CommunicationNumber order by tblLog.Priority desc) as rnk
    FROM (SELECT CommunicationNumber, Count(*) AS Priority, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot 
          FROM Miafon.dbo.tblPhoneLogRep
          WHERE CallDuration > 0
          GROUP BY CommunicationNumber, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot) tblLog)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware about the row_number() function. Let me read about it and understand your solution.

Comment: row_number() function basically ranks each row according to the order by clause you put there. You can use partition to rank each group separatly - like here, for each communicationNumber. and with the order by of the count desc. that way the biggest will be 1 @rahulthewall

Comment: Thanks @sagi, that works. You just need a small correction in your syntax near the end for the query to work properly (at least I needed that).

GROUP BY CommunicationNumber, DayOfWeekSlot, TwoHourSlot) tblLog) tblRank
WHERE tblRank.rnk = 1